# Autocomplete with JSON data fetched via Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, perl, autocomplete

I am trying to use the autocomplete for a search box, the content for the autocomplete is from a  cgi script via Ajax that returns JSON.

Let's start with the javascript portion for my autocomplete. I can get it to work just fine using a hardcoded list, but nothing when I use this.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#search_term').autocomplete({        
    source:function(request, response){
        $.ajax({
            url: './test2.cgi',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                maxRows: 5,
                name_startsWith: request.term
            },
            success: function(data){
                response( $.map(data.matches, function (item){
                    return {
                        label: item.label + "," + item.value,
                        value: item.value
                    }
                }));
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Here is an example of the JSON file that's generated by my test2.cgi perl script.

```
{"matches":[{"value":"color","label":"PATO:0000014"},{"value":"color hue","label":"PATO:0000015"},{"value":"color brightness","label":"PATO:0000016"},{"value":"color saturation","label":"PATO:0000017"},{"value":"color pattern","label":"PATO:0000019"},{"value":"color value","label":"PATO:0000310"}]}
```

I can't figure out where I am going wrong with this.

EDIT 1:
I actually performed an ajax call earlier in the code using similar parameters so I assumed it should work.  Here is the first ajax call, and I know for a fact that this one works since I am able to process the json data and display it on the site

```
function runSearch(term){
$('#results').hide();
$('tbody').empty();

var frmStr = $('#obo_search').serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: './test.cgi',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: frmStr,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        processJSON(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Failed to perform search! textStatus:(" + textStatus + ") and errorThrow: (" + errorThrown + ")");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? does the ajax call actually happened and does the data actually get returned?

Comment: Have a error tag like success and see what the error is. Or have firebug in firefox to debug your javascript.

Comment: Ok, took advice and checked with firebug.Seems like the GET is working, but it's not returning anything.... which is really odd because when I try to use the test2.cgi with a regular input it returns exactly what I need.

Comment: omg. I feel so stupid. I just needed to change the name_startsWith to what my actual input text box's name is. gah! thanks for the help anyways :)

Comment: @whoadiz: Please add your solution as an answer to your question, then accept that answer.  You'll be rewarded with reputation on the site, and this question will no longer be in the list of "unanswered questions".  Cheers!